# Why isn't Mutex unlocking?

Tags: concurrency, rust, mutex, pool

I am trying to implement a global object pool for a large `Obj` type. Here is the code for `POOL`:

```
static mut POOL: Option<Mutex<Vec<Obj>>> = None;
static INIT: Once = ONCE_INIT;

pub struct Obj;
```

Here is how I am accessing and locking `POOL`:

```
fn get_pool<'a>() -> MutexGuard<'a, Vec<Obj>> {
    unsafe {
        match POOL {
            Some(ref mutex) => mutex.lock().unwrap(),
            None            => {
                INIT.call_once(|| {
                    POOL = Some(Mutex::new(vec![]));
                });
                get_pool()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that is causing problems:

```
impl Drop for Obj {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping.");
        println!("hangs here...");
        get_pool().push(Obj {});
    }
}

impl Obj {
    pub fn new() -> Obj {
        println!("initializing");
        get_pool().pop().unwrap_or(Obj {})
        // for some reason, the mutex does not get unlocked at this point...
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the lifetime `'a` of the `MutexGuard` in the return value of `get_pool`. Frankly I'm probably a little confused about the way these lifetime parameters work.

Here is a [link to a playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=432e6ed15f19ee381857012147543f6f&version=nightly&backtrace=0) with a working example. Thanks for your help and merry Christmas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is located in this line:

```
get_pool().pop().unwrap_or(Obj {})
```

Because you call `get_pool()`, you lock the mutex, and it will not be unlocked until the end of the line. However in the call to `unwrap_or()`, you create a new `Obj`. This won't be used if there was an object in the vec. Because it is created later, it will be dropped before the mutex is released. As the drop tries to lock the mutex, you get a deadlock.

To fix this, split that statement across two lines:

```
let o = get_pool().pop();
o.unwrap_or(Obj {})
```

As a related note, you can use [lazy-static](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs) to avoid unsafe code:

```
#![feature(drop_types_in_const)]
use std::sync::{Mutex, MutexGuard};

#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
  static ref POOL: Mutex<Vec<Obj>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
}

pub struct Obj;

fn get_pool<'a>() -> MutexGuard<'a, Vec<Obj>> {
        POOL.lock().unwrap()
}

impl Drop for Obj {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping.");
        println!("hangs here...");
        get_pool().push(Obj {});
        println!("not here...");
    }
}

impl Obj {
    pub fn new() -> Obj {
        println!("initializing");
        let o = get_pool().pop();
        o.unwrap_or(Obj {})
    }
}

fn main() {
    Obj::new();
    Obj::new();
    println!("Now reaches this point.");
}
```

**edit**

As requested I'll explain how I diagnosed this;

1. First I verified if I could reproduce the problem using the sample you gave. Which I could, and the code was simple and clear enough. This was all fine, I only needed to add the line `println!("not here...");` to be 100% sure it hangs at the statement above, and not at the end of the block.
2. In a first scan, I noticed that `Obj::new();` had to be called twice for the problem to happen. So the next goal is to find the differences between both calls. (My knowledge of rust is not good enough yet to spot this error by just reading the code).
3. Because `POOL` is not initialized in the first call, I added the initializing at the start of main (`unsafe{INIT.call_once(||{POOL=Some(Mutex::new(vec![]));});}`), but that did not change anything.
4. Because an object is added to the pool when `Obj` is dropped, I added an object at the start of main (`get_pool().push(Obj {});`). Now it hangs at the first `Obj::new();`.
5. I could further simplify it by calling `get_pool().pop().unwrap_or(Obj {});` next in main.
6. Now I could partly remove or split that line to determine exactly where it hangs. By doing that I saw I was able to fix it. Then I realized an extra `Obj` was created there. Note that rust borrow scopes are currently [lexical](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811).
7. In retrospect, I would have spotted this earlier if I removed the line containing `get_pool()` in `drop()`, and counted how many times `drop()` was called. I did not realize is was called three times instead of twice.

As a general note, the title of this question is "Why isn't Mutex unlocking". This could be interpreted as a compiler bug, or a bug in the standard library. Most of the time (>99%) it is not. It is important to keep that in mind, and not focus on the wrong issue.

This problem is related to global shared state. Try to avoid that. (Yes I know that's not always possible).

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem both on this version and the complicated real version that it is based on. Is there any chance you would be willing to describe the process you used for figuring it out?

Comment: I would not have solved this without your simplified example! Ok, I will add some details about the process tomorrow.